# Hide street names in Open Street Maps

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I'm implementing OpenStreetMaps in my Android application and I have a question. Is there currently an option to hide street names in Open Street Maps? I have no need to hide the names of cities or anything - only streets

Answer (score 0):

Check [Leaflet Provider Demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) to see if there is a style that fits your needs.